# Auto-Restock Woocommerce Canceled orders for time-out orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So @LoicTheAztec helped me out with some code to get auto-restock working for canceled orders. What I have found is that the code works only when the Admin cancels an order in the panel.

When Payment isn't fulfilled or if the customer cancels his order stock isn't replenished. Have no idea how I would make this work...

Here's the code we are using:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Auto_Stock_Restore' ) ) {
    class WC_Auto_Stock_Restore {

        function __construct() {
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_cancelled', array( $this, 'restore_order_stock' ), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_cancelled', array( $this, 'restore_order_stock' ), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_cancelled', array( $this, 'restore_order_stock' ), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_refunded', array( $this, 'restore_order_stock' ), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_to_refunded', array( $this, 'restore_order_stock' ), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_refunded', array( $this, 'restore_order_stock' ), 10, 2 );
        }

        public function restore_order_stock( $order_id, $order ) {
            $items = $order->get_items();

            if ( ! get_option('woocommerce_manage_stock') == 'yes' && ! count( $items ) > 0 )
                    return; // We exit

            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

                if ( $product_id > 0 ) {
                    $product = $item->get_product();

                    if ( $product && $product->exists() && $product->managing_stock() ) {

                        // Get the product initial stock quantity (before update)
                        $initial_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

                        $item_qty = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', $item->get_quantity(), $this, $item );

                        // Update the product stock quantity
                        // Replace DEPRECATED methods: increase_stock() & discrease_stock()
                        wc_update_product_stock( $product, $item_qty, 'increase' );

                        // Get the product updated stock quantity
                        $updated_stock = $initial_stock + $item_qty;

                        do_action( 'woocommerce_auto_stock_restored', $product, $item );

                        // A unique Order note: Store each order note in an array…
                        $order_note[] = sprintf( __( 'Product ID #%s stock incremented from %s to %s.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_id, $initial_stock, $updated_stock);

                        // DEPRECATED & NO LONGER NEEDED - can be removed
                        //$order->send_stock_notifications( $product, $updated_stock, $item_qty );

                    }
                }
            }
            // Adding a unique composite order note (for multiple items)
            $order_notes = count($order_note) > 1 ? implode(' | ', $order_note) : $order_note[0];
            $order->add_order_note( $order_notes );
        }
    }
    $GLOBALS['wc_auto_stock_restore'] = new WC_Auto_Stock_Restore();
```